# Why compile file have function name?

Tags: c, function, variables, gcc, compiler-construction

I have a c program:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
long fibo(int n); 
int main(void) 
{ 
        int input = 0; 
 
        printf("Enter your number: "); 
        scanf("%i", &input); 
 
        /*check buffer*/ 
        if (getchar() != '\n' || input <= 0) 
        { 
                printf("Try again\n"); 
                return 0; 
        } 
 
        printf("result: %li\n", fibo(input)); 
 
        return 1; 
} 
 
long fibo(int n) 
{ 
        if (n > 2) 
        { 
                return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
                return 1; 
        } 
}
```

I compiled it with gcc.

```
000035e0: 735f 7374 6172 7400 6d61 696e 0066 6962  s_start.**main.fib**
000035f0: 6f00 5f5f 6973 6f63 3939 5f73 6361 6e66  **o**.__isoc99_scanf
```

When I review compile file, I see functions name(main and fibo) but I couldn't find variables name.

My question is why compiler keep function name? And what is usage? If for developersreview binery file and deassembling why didn't save variables name?

I am new

[Objdump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRfl9.jpg)

Comment: How exactly did you compile?

Comment: By "compile file" do you mean the object file, or the executable?  What command are you using to produce it?

Comment: It's related to "linkage".  The program needs the function names so that they can be called — especially `main()` is called by the startup code.  You could make `fibo` into a static function; then the compiler would not need to keep the name `fibo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run strings over either the object file or the binary it has a string fibo.  You didn't say what platform you are using but this is on Linux.  Linux these days use the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format (pie for executable, and lsb relocable for the object file.  The symbols, like function names, are stored in the symbol table.  A better way to inspect it is using `nm` (or `objdump`):

```
$ nm fibo.o
0000000000000000 T fibo
                 U getchar
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U __isoc99_scanf
000000000000003f T main
                 U printf
                 U puts
```

and the executable:

```
$ nm fibo
0000000000004048 B __bss_start
0000000000004048 b completed.0
                 w __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000004038 D __data_start
0000000000004038 W data_start
00000000000010b0 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000001120 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000003df0 d __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000004040 D __dso_handle
0000000000003df8 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000004048 D _edata
0000000000004050 B _end
0000000000001165 T fibo
0000000000001294 T _fini
0000000000001160 t frame_dummy
0000000000003de8 d __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
000000000000219c r __FRAME_END__
                 U getchar@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000004000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000002034 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000001000 t _init
0000000000003df0 d __init_array_end
0000000000003de8 d __init_array_start
0000000000002000 R _IO_stdin_used
                 U __isoc99_scanf@GLIBC_2.7
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000001290 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000001230 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000011a4 T main
                 U printf@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U puts@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000010e0 t register_tm_clones
0000000000001080 T _start
0000000000004048 D __TMC_END__
```

Answer (score 0):

Any non-static functions or variables declared at file scope are exportable symbols.  Their names are made available when a module is compiled so that other modules may references them.

For example, suppose you had two source files:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void);

int main()
{
    printf("in main\n");
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    printf("in foo\n");
}
```

When foo.c is compiled into foo.o, the name of the function `foo` appears in the object file.  When main.c is compiled to main.o it contains a reference to `foo`.  Then when the two are linked into an executable, the name is used to satisfy the reference in main.o to use the function in foo.o.